# extract map from nested case classes

Tags: scala

I have a json value which i have read into nested case class.
From this i need a scala map of (category,rating).Please help.

Expected output:

```
Map("MTH1"-> "9A","MTH2"-> "9B","SCI1" -> "8A")
```

Note: If any value is none, then it should be omitted.

Need some elegant and smart way to convert the values into scala Map

```
 val myVal: List[myClass] = List(myClass("Tim", "100", Some("hills"),
    List(subject("geometry", Some("MTH1"), Some("9A")),
      subject("trigonometry", Some("MTH2"), Some("9B")),
      subject("physics", Some("SCI1"), Some("8A"))
    )))


  case class myClass(
                      name: String,
                      classId: String,
                      teacher: Option[String],
                      subjects: List[subject]
                    )


  case class subject(
                      name: String,
                      category: Option[String],
                      rating: Option[String]
                    )

  myVal.foreach(i =>
    (
      i.subjects.foreach(
        j => println(j.category.get, j.rating.get)
      )))
```

Comment: What do you want it to do if either the category or rating are missing (`None`)? Leave the subject out of the map?

Comment: Your "expected output" is not valid because you can't have a `Map` with two keys that are the same, and this `Map` has two keys that are "maths". It will just become `Map("maths"-> "9B","science" -> "8A")`

Comment: Your expected output won’t work as a map, because there are two keys called “math”, and keys need to be unique. Would a list of pairs work for you?

Comment: Sorry keys are not same. I am updating.

Comment: do not give negative voting. i have tried my best to clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The will return a `List[Map[String,String]]`:

```
myVal.map(_.subjects
           .collect{
             case subject(_,Some(cat),Some(rat)) => cat -> rat
           }.toMap)
```

Each element of the original `List` is turned into a `Map` of `category -> rating` (key -> value) pairs.

Comment: Will there be multiple maps in the list ? I think no right?

Comment: Read the sentence I wrote after the code, or just run the code and find out. If the `myVal` list has 2 `myClass` elements then this code will return a `List` with 2 separate and independent `Map` elements.